# How can I make this repeat forever?

Tags: python, loops

I have this code which generates random characters (it's a kind of terrain generator). I just can't get it to print forever. Here's the current code I have for it:

```
import random
print(' '.join([random.choice(['#','o','~','*']) for i in range(10000)]))
```

I tried to do this, but I got a `SyntaxError`.

```
import random
print(' '.join([random.choice(['#','o','~','*']) while True]))
```

How can I get this to repeat forever? I also want a 0.05 second delay in between the printing of each character.

Comment: You can't make a list comprehension with `while`! Why not just use a standard loop?

Comment: `random.choice('#o~*')` is shorter (and maybe clearer?)

Comment: You would be so much better off spending less time trying to implement everything in as few characters as possible and more time thinking about what you're actually trying to achieve. Hard drives are cheaper than time. Just build a standard generator function, and call it for as long as you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if you want a delay between the characters, you can't use `join()` because that will give you a single string instead of a "character generator".

And if you plan on using an "infinite" generator, you can't use `join()` either for that same reason.

How about this:

```
import random
import sys
import time
while True:
    print(random.choice("#o~*"), end="", flush=True) # Python 3.3 and up
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.write(..)`? (since you're already calling flush..)

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` when I run this. Is this built for python 3?

Comment: @SomeGuy: Yes, since you were using Python 3 syntax (`print` as a function) and `range` instead of `xrange`, I assumed that was the version you were targeting.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oops, I guess I failed to realize that I had just re-written this in my python 2.x editor.

Comment: In the latest version of Python, `print` has the keyword argument `flush`. You can reduce the length of your code by two lines.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: Thanks, I didn't know that. Nice feature!

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a loop inside your print function, you must put your print function inside a loop, so for example:

```
while True:
    print random.choice(['#','o','~','*']),
```

Comment: Well, you *could* do this... but why the `join`?

Comment: `print(random.choice(['#','o','~','*']))` is sufficient. To not print `\n` add `, end=""`.

Comment: Oh let me fix that, I was just focused on illustrating that you can't embed a loop within a print statement, I forgot to check the actual print statement. (Thank you for catching that!)

Comment: Sorry about that, since I am more geared for C++ it's a hard habit to kick. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: You forgot the comma on the end of `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this simplified version of you code:

```
import random, sys, time
while True: sys.stdout.write(random.choice('#o~*') + ' '); time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: Did you try this? It prints a random character, a space, `2` (the result of `sys.stdout.write()`) and a newline. Repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: Did you run this in IDLE or the command line? If so, the interpreter will show the results of `sys.stdout.write(random.choice('#o~*') + ' ')` as two (meaning two bytes were written). If you run this as a program, you will not have that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a new approach.

### Roll your own

```
import random
import time

class GenerateRandomChar(object):
    def __init__(self, charlist):
        self.charlist = charlist
    def __next__(self):
        return random.choice(self.charlist)

terrain_tiles = GenerateRandomChar("#o~*")
while True:
    print(next(terrain_tiles), end='')
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Also if you're building a map, you may want to think about something like:

```
class Map(list):
    def __init__(self, terrain_tiles, WIDTH=12, HEIGHT=12):
        self.WIDTH = WIDTH
        self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT
        self.terrain_tiles = GenerateRandomChar(terrain_tiles)
        for y in range(self.HEIGHT):
            self.append([next(self.terrain_tiles) for x in range(self.WIDTH)])
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([" ".join([tile for tile in row]) for row in self])

>>> map_ = Map("~o#*")
>>> print(map_)
o o o o o o ~ ~ # ~ ~ ~
# # # o o # o # o # * #
~ o # * ~ # o # * ~ # ~
o * o o o * # o # o # *
# * o # # # * o ~ * # #
# ~ o ~ * # # ~ o o ~ ~
~ * # # o ~ o * # # ~ o
# o * o o * o * ~ ~ o *
# # * * ~ ~ ~ * # * # o
o o ~ ~ # * ~ ~ * ~ * o
~ * ~ ~ * # * * ~ # o #
* o ~ # ~ # ~ ~ o o o o
```

Answer (score 2):

Infinite iterator with random symbols:

```
import itertools
it = (random.choice(['#','o','~','*']) for i in itertools.repeat(""))
```

As some people have commented, `join()` won't help you because it generates the whole string before returning. You can try (Python 3):

```
[print(char, end="") for char in it] # not such a good idea
```

or

```
for char in it: print(char, end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use generators:

```
from itertools import repeat
import random
from time import sleep
import sys

gen = (random.choice(['#','o','~','*']) for _ in repeat(None))
for x in gen:
    print x,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: itertools can do anything <3 <3 <3. For real though I've never used `itertools.repeat`