# I want to repeat a function indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am working through some exercises on python and my task is to create a program that can take a number, divide it by 2 if it is an even number.  Or it will take the number, multiply it by 3, then add 1.  It should ask for an input and afterwards it should wait for another input.

My code looks like this, mind you I am new to all this.

```
print('Please enter a number:')

def numberCheck(c):
    if c % 2 == 0:
        print(c // 2)
    elif c % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * c + 1)

c = int(input())
numberCheck(c)
```

I want it to print "Please enter a number" only once. but after running I want it to wait for another number.  How would I do this?

I tried a `for` loop but that uses a range and I don't want to set a range unless there is a way to do it to infinity.

Comment: So, I am thinking about your current predicament, but I am also curious. Is there a reason you are using floor division?

Comment: `while True` is your friend. Also since you seem to be a Python beginner, may I suggest to use PEP8 naming style? ie no `camelCase` names but rather `snake_case`

Comment: I don't know, it is only chapter 3 of the book and I am doing as told lol

Comment: If you are using Python 3.9 or above, use `while (c:= int(input()): numberCheck(c)` to get an infinite loop

Comment: The linked question is not really a duplicate, it asks specifically for a possibility of an infinite loop using a `for` statement, while this one is about infinite loops in general. A better duplicate target would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335680/how-can-i-make-this-repeat-forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an infinite loop, that can be done with a while loop.

```
print('Please enter a number:')

def numberCheck(c):
        if c % 2 == 0:
            print(c // 2)
        elif c % 2 == 1:
            print(3 * c + 1)
            
while True:
    c = int(input())
    numberCheck(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is you want the function to run indefinitely. this is my approach, through the use of a while loop

```
print("Enter a number")

while True:
  c = int(input(""))
  numberCheck(c)
```

Comment: Minor nit: It should be `while True:` (Capital T)

Comment: @Slakker well, it's not minor!

Comment: Worked perfect thank you.  When I tried a while loop I put the while True in the wrong spot because I did not get the expected result, but now I do see why this would work,

Comment: why do you say it's not memory efficient? Memory should not accumulate here if i understand garbage collection correctly

Comment: That was a misunderstanding from me

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop with `True`:

```py
while True:
    c = int(input())
    numberCheck(c)
```